# improve my question on class design/ List or single param

Tags: support, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930951/design-help-test-case-test-step-test-data has 3 down votes. i added a note at the bottom explaining what i have. Is it enough information. i was not asking for a vote but a best practice of a similar case would help.

Comment: At least capitalize the first letter of the first sentence in your original question. First impressions and everything. Still parsing the rest... done. Your question looks like it's about design rather than implementation. There are many possible design decisions that can be taken depending on your requirements, and which one is the "best" is ultimately a subjective matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment of the question reflects pretty much what is wrong there :

> What is your actual question? What have you tried so far? Have you got a small code example to help illustrate your question?

Now, the community seems to think agree that the problem is :

> [image]

Don't get me wrong though you can still change the question.

Work on your question. Give samples of things you tried or at least try to prove that you actually looked for an answer. Read the help center carefully and make sure your questions fits the Q&A format and you will automatically receive better feedback.